# Why this record structure is compiling but giving runtime error

Tags: record, freepascal

I am trying following code with a simple record of string and integer:

```
program Progrecords; 

Type  
    Progrec = Record  
        pname : string;  
        pnum : integer; 
        end;  

var 
    Progs : Array of Progrec; 
    aprog, pp: Progrec; 

begin 
    aprog.pname := 'abc';
    aprog.pnum := 4; 
    Progs[0] := aprog;

    aprog.pname := 'def';
    aprog.pnum := 6; 
    Progs[1] := aprog;

    for pp in Progs do begin
        writeln('Name: ',pp.pname, '; Num: ', pp.pnum); 
    end;
end.
```

It compiles OK but give runtime error:

```
$ fpc rnrecords.pas && ./rnrecords
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling rnrecords.pas
rnrecords.pas(17,2) Warning: Variable "Progs" of a managed type does not seem to be initialized
Linking rnrecords
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?
27 lines compiled, 0.1 sec
1 warning(s) issued

Runtime error 216 at $0000000000400226
  $0000000000400226
  $000000000040018C
```

I am working on Debian Stable Linux with fpc version 3.0.0

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Progs` is a dynamic array and has to be allocated before use.

Comment: .. which the compiler already tells - search for "warning" in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Progs` is a dynamic array and has to be allocated before use.

For example:

```
SetLength(Progs,2);  // Allocates two records
```

See [Dynamic Array](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array)

Comment: Can we increase the length of array after setting it once?

Comment: Yes, increasing preserves the existing elements.